# Mount EncFS volume on Mac OS X works from user account but fails with root using su

Tags: mac-osx, bash, scripting, shell

I'm trying to automatically mount an EncFS volume by using login/logout hook scripts on Mac OS X. The scripts are run as root and automatically run user defined hooks as the user logging in or out. The main scripts are in `/usr/local/sbin` and are called `loginhook` and `logouthook`. Here is the login script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOCAL_HOOK="/Users/$1/.loginhook"

if [ -e "$LOCAL_HOOK" ]
then
  su - $1 -c "bash $LOCAL_HOOK"
fi
```

The script is registered to execute on login with:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /usr/local/sbin/loginhook
```

User defined `.loginhook`:

```
ENCFS=/path/to/encfs
PWD=$(security find-generic-password -ga EncFS 2>&1 >/dev/null | cut -d'"' -f2)
echo $PWD | $ENCFS -S $HOME/.encrypted/Vault $HOME/Documents/Vault
```

The redirection for the `security` command is necessary since normal output goes to stdout but the password goes to stderr and looks like `password: "mypass"`.

If I execute `.localhook` from my user account the script works fine, but if the script gets executed from the "parent" script (which runs as root) by using `su` I get a blank password.

Debugging with `bash -x` shows that everything runs as it should, but the `env` command reveals that the environment is *not* the same as when I log in despite using `su -` in the script. I suspect this is where the problem lies but I'm stumped as to what it is.

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: LaunchAgent solution based on information from Gordon Davisson.

`encfsd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

ENCFS="/path/to/encfs"
ENCDIR="$HOME/.encrypted/Vault"
DECDIR="$HOME/Documents/Vault"

function cleanup {
  # Kill sleep command ($! is PID of last command launched in background)
  kill $!
  umount "$DECDIR"
  exit
}
trap cleanup 1 2 3 6 15

security find-generic-password -ga EncFS 2>&1 >/dev/null | cut -d'"' -f2 | "$ENCFS" -S "$ENCDIR" "$DECDIR"

# Wait for exit
while true; do
  # Sleeping ignores normal signals so start it in a subprocess and wait for it
  sleep 3600 &
  wait
done
```

`~/Library/LaunchAgents/localhost.encfsd.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <false/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>localhost.encfsd</string>
  <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
  <string>Background</string>
  <key>Program</key>
  <string>/Users/asdf/bin/encfsd.sh</string>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login- and logouthook scripts run before & after (respectively) the user session, not within the session.  I suspect that since your loginhook is running before the user session starts, the user's keychain hasn't been unlocked yet, so you can't recover passwords from it yet.  A LaunchAgent might work better for this...

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I have made a LaunchAgent solution and will include the the details in the question.